# Unexpected performance observed in repa-algorithms function

Tags: haskell, repa

I was testing out the `mmultP` function from `repa-algorithms-3.2.1.1` with the following code (a tad condensed here for brevity):

```
import Data.Array.Repa hiding            (map)
import Data.Array.Repa.Algorithms.Matrix (mmultP)

import Control.Monad                     (replicateM)
import Control.Arrow                     ((&&&))
import System.Random.MWC                 (initialize, uniformR)
import Control.Monad.ST                  (runST)
import Data.Vector.Unboxed               (singleton)
import Data.Word                         (Word32)

-- Create a couple of dense matrices
genRnds :: Word32 -> [Double]
genRnds seed = runST $ do
    gen <- initialize (singleton seed)
    replicateM (1000 ^ 2) (uniformR (0, 1) gen)

(arr, brr) = head &&& last $ map (fromListUnboxed (Z :. 1000 :. 1000 :: DIM2) . genRnds) [1, 100000]

-- mmultP test
main :: IO ()
main = mmultP arr brr >>= print
```

and as specified [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa/3.2.1.1/doc/html/Data-Array-Repa.html), compiled using

```
ghc mmultTest.hs -Odph -rtsopts -threaded -fno-liberate-case -funfolding-use-threshold1000 -funfolding-keeness-factor1000 -fllvm -optlo-O3 -fforce-recomp
```

Here's the sequential run in the threaded runtime:

```
$ time ./mmultTest +RTS -K100M > /dev/null
real    0m10.962s
user    0m10.790s
sys     0m0.161s
```

and here's one using 4 cores (running on a four-core MacBook Air):

```
$ time ./mmultTest +RTS -N4 -K100M > /dev/null
real    0m13.008s
user    0m18.591s
sys     0m2.067s
```

Anyone have any intuition as to what's happening here?  I also get slower-than-sequential performance for `-N2` and `-N3`; each core seems to add some additional time.

Note that I *do* observe some minor gains from parallelism on some hand-rolled Repa matrix multiply code.

**UPDATE**:

Puzzling; I replaced `main` with

```
mmultBench :: IO ()
mmultBench  = do 
   results <- mmultP arr brr 
   let reduced = sumAllS results 
   print reduced
```

and removed the dependency on `mwc-random`:

```
(arr, brr) = head &&& last $ map (fromListUnboxed (Z :. 1000 :. 1000 :: DIM2)) (replicate 2 [1..1000000])
```

A Criterion benchmark with the runtime options `-N1 -K100M` yields:

```
mean: 1.361450 s, lb 1.360514 s, ub 1.362915 s, ci 0.950
std dev: 5.914850 ms, lb 3.870615 ms, ub 9.183472 ms, ci 0.950
```

and `-N4 -K100M` gives me:

```
mean: 556.8201 ms, lb 547.5370 ms, ub 573.5012 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 61.82764 ms, lb 40.15479 ms, ub 102.5329 ms, ci 0.950
```

Which is a lovely speedup.  I would almost think that the previous behaviour was due to writing the resulting 1000x1000 array to stdout, but as I mentioned, I do observe parallelism gains there if I swap in my own matrix multiply code.  Still scratching my head.

Comment: What do you get when using 3 cores?

Comment: Also slower-than-sequential, but faster than `-N4`.  Same situation for `-N2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Printing the matrix to stdout will make the program IO bound. Any speedup figures recorded in this situation will be lies.

2) There are no 4 core MacBook Airs. They are all 2 core, with 2 hyper-threads per core. Only 2 threads can actually run at a time. Any speedup with > -N2 will be due to latency hiding -- the second hyper-thread on a core can run while the first is stalled on cache-miss.

Comment: Thanks, that was my suspicion.  Swapping in the hand-rolled code resulted in slower performance than `mmultP` across-the-board, but it did yield slightly quicker times under `-N2` and `-N4` than w/`-N1`.  That was the source of my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

This does seem strange, but maybe you are just making the usual payment for parallelism but not reaping the benefits? --So it's akin to parallelizing with absurdly unbalanced loads?

It seems like something more must be wrong. What struck me, though -- and it might give a partial explanation of your results --  is that you are only using one `repa` combinator, `mmultP`. The framework hardly gets a chance! If I complicate the matter with a sprinking of `zipWith`, `foldAllP` etc. -- e.g.

```
main :: IO ()
main =  arr `xxx` brr >>= foldAllP (+) 0 >>= print where
   xxx arr brr = R.zipWith (+) <$> complicated arr <*> complicated brr
   complicated = mmultP brr >=> mmultP arr >=> mmultP brr >=> mmultP arr
```

Then with my two-core jalopy, I get exactly the two-core-parallelizer's dream:

```
 $ time ./mmmult +RTS -K200M  -N2
 6.2713897715510016e16

 real   0m8.742s
 user   0m16.176s
 sys    0m0.444s

 $ time ./mmmult +RTS -K200M  
 6.2713897715512584e16

 real   0m15.214s
 user   0m14.970s
 sys    0m0.239s
```

Comment: Yeah, I get that nice speedup from your code as well.  I actually almost fooled myself when updating this question, because I had done some parallel reductions with `sumAllP` et al that improved my times under `-N4` nicely; it seems like I'm really just not getting the desired utilisation on `mmultP`.  Do you get similar times using the simple `main = mmultP arr brr >>= print` from my example?

Comment: Yes, my result was akin to yours for the original module. But the more complicated I made main the better my results, as least as far as parallelizing goes.